# Why my table-value type is not accepted by stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I prepared a table type in my SQL Server like this:

```
USE iSMS

CREATE TYPE [i_Flow].[VersandTbl] AS TABLE
                                     (
                                         [VERSID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
                                         -- more stuff
                                     )
```

The type now is visible under "Types/User-Defined Table types.

Now I'm trying to write a stored procedure who use this type like:

```
USE iSMS
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [i_Flow].[sp_Versand_INSERTTest]
    (@vitem VersandTbl READONLY)
```

Also tried:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [i_Flow].[sp_Versand_INSERTTest]
    (@vitem i_Flow.VersandTbl READONLY)
```

In both cases I'm getting the information, that `READONLY` can't used, because it is not a table-valued parameter. And also that the variable has an invalid data type.

Maybe I missed anything?

I read a lot of documentation and howtos. But they all showing this way of using the table type. Currently i don't know, what to do.

Comment: What version of sql server you're working with?  [can't reproduce](https://dbfiddle.uk/5Rot_s3s)

Comment: Are you sure you are connected to the right server and database? Are you sure your user has permission to use that table type? Side note: you should probably consider a clustered primary key on your table type (declare it inline)

Comment: Are you seeing this message when you actually execute it or just in intellisense? If just intellisense you need to refresh the cache so it knows about the newly created type

Comment: @MartinSmith Thank you very much.. This was the problem. Forgot to refresh the cache.